# inflate an independent linearLayout into other XML defined layout

Tags: android, runtime, android-linearlayout

Can I add linearLayouts which is defined in XML in another linearLayout which has a parent containing many layouts. For example in this case I have a parent LinearLayout having to element: a scrollView and a LinearLayout. The scrollView has a LinearLayout which is initially defined empty in the XML. I want to add layouts to this LinearLayout so that if the user exceeds the bottom of the screen then the layouts can be in scrollView.

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener{


EditText date;
LinearLayout row[]=new LinearLayout[30];
int rowNo=0;
LinearLayout itemForm=(LinearLayout)LinearLayout.inflate(this, R.id.item_form,null);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
    date.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(arg1==false){

        row[rowNo++]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.row);
        itemForm.addView(row[rowNo]);

    }
}

 }
```

This is the XML layout containing the parent LinearLayout with its scrollView and LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ActivityMain" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:weightSum="10">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="date" />

<TextView  android:id="@+id/code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="voucher Code"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2">  
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/item_form"
              android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout that i want to inflate in the other linearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/row" >


<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter item name"
            android:id="@+id/item"/>

  <EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:inputType="number"
  android:hint="Quantity"
  android:id="@+id/quant" />

  <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal"
      android:hint="Rate"
      android:id="@+id/quant" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is issue ? error ?

Comment: java nullPointerException @ itemForm.addView(row[rowNo]);

Comment: Try my answer and let me know it works or not.

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Comment: @kayveesin could you also tell what you are trying to do with array of Linearlayouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using following way to inflate xml :

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(
            getApplicationContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.yourlayoutfilename, null);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_form)).addView(viewToLoad);
```

And for Addview :

```
LinearLayout itemForm=(LinearLayout) viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.item_form);
itemForm.addView(.......);
```

Comment: Also, how can i assign a unique id to every editText that is created

Comment: Use setTag() method to set unique Tag to each EditText and by using getTag() you can retrieve it. And yes congratulations. Glad to help.

Comment: i didn't get. plz can you elaborate??? like, where should i use the setTag() and the getTag() methods???